# Remove class only depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to remove .btn-group from the divs while the screen is less than 1339px, so that the layout isn't affected on smaller screens. I'm using bootstrap v3.

I like the feel of the layout using just navbar for <1339px, so I'd like to just remove the split buttons during those viewports. However I'd like to keep them for >1340.  I'd like it to look like https://youtu.be/qpWlaOeGZ_4?t=10m38s.

I'm not quite sure where to start or how to do it. I've looked at several answers from other threads but they don't seem to work.

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Mommy Info</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">Home</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="splash"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--home-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">Preg</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="splash"> <a href="#">Preg</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ttc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">fd</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">gp</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">lad</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--preg-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">aab</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">advice</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">guidelines</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">milestones</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ld</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--aab-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">han</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li><!--han -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">MM</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!-- pm-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">MM</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!-- mm-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">S</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">HB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">DB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">BG</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--s-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn navbar-btn">R</a>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">RGames</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rgear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rlearn</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--r-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn">B</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!--b -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/L9dzjxpg/

ANSWER:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 1340){
        $('.btn-group').addClass('backup-btn-group').removeClass('btn-group');
        $('.btn').addClass('backup-btn').removeClass('btn');
        $('.mybtn').addClass('dropdown-toggle').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
        $('.myanchor').addClass('anchor');
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 1340){
        $('.btn-group').addClass('backup-btn-group').removeClass('btn-group');
        $('.btn').addClass('backup-btn').removeClass('btn');
        $('.mybtn').addClass('dropdown-toggle').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
        $('.myanchor').addClass('anchor');
    }else{
        $('.backup-btn-group').addClass('btn-group').removeClass('backup-btn-group');
        $('.backup-btn').addClass('btn').removeClass('backup-btn');
        $('.mybtn').removeClass('dropdown-toggle').removeAttribute("data-toggle");
        $('.myanchor').removeClass('anchor');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should rephrase your title as mobile typically means phones and tablets.  Based on your question the remove of the class is dependent on the screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 1340){
    $('.btn-group').addClass('backup-btn-group').removeClass('btn-group');
  }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 1340){
    $('.btn-group').addClass('backup-btn-group').removeClass('btn-group');
  }else{
    $('.backup-btn-group').addClass('btn-group').removeClass('backup-btn-group');
  }
});
```

I made it add a class "backup-btn-group" so if the window becomes bigger than 1340 it replaces the original class, but you can do that keeping it in a var

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, and you are, you should already be including jQuery, it's required for Bootstrap to work properly. Create a custom JS file and throw this in there, and include it AFTER the jQuery file.

Comment: that /\ or add a script tag after closing the footer tag, than put this code inside it

Comment: Thank you! (I have jQuery linked, I just don't really know how to use it)

Comment: It's not working, I tried both ways. It still has all of the btn-group styles. (Or maybe it's the btn class?). I'm not sure.

Comment: If you want to remove another class instead btn-group just change it inside the code

Comment: Thank you! To do it how I wanted exactly, I used your code and added a couple lines : 
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 1340){
        $('.btn').addClass('backup-btn').removeClass('btn');
        $('.mybtn').addClass('dropdown-toggle').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
        $('.myanchor').addClass('anchor');
    }else{
                $('.backup-btn').addClass('btn').removeClass('backup-btn');
        $('.mybtn').removeClass('dropdown-toggle').removeAttribute("data-toggle");
        $('.myanchor').removeClass('anchor');
    }

Comment: Ok, glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
if($(window).width < 1340){
 $('.btn-group').hide();
}
else{
 $('.btn-group').show();
}
});
```

You should hide .btn-group window width lesser than 1340 using CSS. So it won't display on load.